# Python saying that it cant find pygame

Tags: python, pygame

At the top of my python code, I put import pygame as usual, and have installed the module on my computer. So why do i get this when running my code? I have already tried deleting pygame and reinstalling it and it has not worked. The files are on my computer. Can anyone help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<myuser>\Documents\RPG\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: How did you install pygame? If it's into a virtual env, have you activated it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have added the python path when you installed python. If you're using windows, search for Edit the system environment variables. Click on Environment variables, in the system variables section, double click on **path** -- and add the path of your python software.
ex: **C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\ & C:\Program Files\Python310***

Comment: very much doubt that this is the issue, they said they installed it so... they probably have it a added to PATH, the issue is pretty clearly with environments

Comment: also, it's `python` complaining about a module not being there (where its looking), hence we can assume that `python` itself was available.